# Chrome extension: How to make my tabs query return the URL without anything after the .com/

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I would like to get the URL as the website's domain name rather than having the extra parts after the ".com/"

Currently when I query tabs with `chrome.tabs.query(params, function(){...});` the URL will still contain all the content about the specific page rather than just being the website's domain

How should I go about this so that it will also work with .ca or .gov as well? Is there a trick to shrink the string after the domain ends or will I have to look for string patterns in the URL for each different ending

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can parse the result and extract the domain name from it.

```
let result = 'https://example.com/some/after?=after:stuf&';
const url = new URL(result);
const domain = url.hostname;
console.log(domain);
```

OUTPUT

```
example.com
```

Answer (score 2):

Given [Tab.url](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/reference/tabs/#property-Tab-url) is a plain string, you can run it through the `URL` constructor and get the [origin](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URL/origin) from that

```js
// just for the demo
const tabs = [{
  url: "https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73524018/chrome-extension-how-to-make-my-tabs-query-return-the-url-without-anything-afte",
}, {
  url: "https://example.com/foo/bar/baz?msg=Hello%20World",
}];

const origins = tabs.map(({ url }) => new URL(url).origin);
console.log(origins);
```